# How to restore a hidden window?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to be able to hide a window by clicking a button. Then when I click another, it restores.

This is the code I use to hide the window (Using Notepad as an example):

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int hWnd;
        Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
        {
            if (pr.ProcessName == "notepad")
            {
                hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
                ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I try to use this code to restore it, it won't work:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int hWnd;
        Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
        {
            if (pr.ProcessName == "notepad")
            {
                hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
                ShowWindow(hWnd, 5);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are no exceptions or anything, it just doesn't do anything.
EDIT: I have used different nCmdShow integers. Those being 1,5 and 9.

Comment: In order to restore window, you should use `nCmdShow` = 9 (`SW_RESTORE`) instead of 5 (`SW_SHOW`)

Comment: As I edited, I have tried that. But it just gives the same result.

Comment: Try visible = true/false.

Comment: are you sure notepad is still in the available process?

Comment: jdweng, there is no visibility property in System.DIagnostics.Process

Comment: Dr. Stitch, I am pretty sure it is still in the available processes, When I go into task manager, it is in the background processes.